# Inconsistent readings of magnetic fields between two electric vehicles

Tags: emf

I measured the strength of magnetic field in two electric vehicles from different automakers. Both measurements were done while the vehicle was driving at non-trivial speed.

- Vehicle 1 showed under 0.6 milligauss (near the sensitivity limit of the devices.)
- Vehicle 2 showed up to 10 milligauss.

I'm surprised by such a big difference. This should probably suggest automaker 1 did a better job of shielding of HV components, but as an electricity n00b, I was wondering if there's still something that could make the device I used ([TriField Meter Model 100XE](https://www.trifield.com/product/trifield-emf-meter-model-100xe/)) unsuitable to measure the field in vehicle 1. The label on the device reads "Electric and magnetic settings are frequency weighted and calibrated for 60Hz sine waves".

Both vehicle are said to have a "permanent-magnet synchronous AC motor".

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the measurements and why? Do the readings make any difference?

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid being in high levels of EMF when possible.

Comment: I would not expect a 60 Hz measurement device to give sensible readings from a car that is not powered by 60 Hz AC.

Comment: So basically you are asking if 10 milligauss is low or high level? For a normal person living in normal world you have nothing to worry about. If you feel like you are afraid of magnetic fields, perhaps consult professional healthcare experts.

Comment: Thanks all. My question was specifically whether I can trust the readings I'm getting, and @user1850479 answered just that.

Answer (score 2):

> *I'm just trying to avoid being in high levels of EMF when possible.*

- 10 mG (milli gauss) in teslas is 1 μT
- The earth's own magnetic field is around 60 μT at its maximum

> *Vehicle 1 showed under 0.6 milligauss (near the sensitivity limit of
> the devices.) Vehicle 2 showed up to 10 milligauss.*

I don't think you are in any danger.